# Lync 2013 and Office 2010

Tags: ms-office, outlook-2010, lync, office-2010, lync-2013

I am having issues with a recent deployment of Lync 2013 where we are unable to find any contacts from the address book or outlook. It appears to be linked to the fact that the users still remain on office 2010.

It works with Lync 2010 and also works in Lync 2013 when we have office 2013.

Anyone have any suggestions/workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You might try running a Repair on the Office 2010 installation and see if that resolves the communications issue.